# onBeforeUnload cancels HTTP request on page leave

Tags: javascript, html, http, dom, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a http request when I leave the page with the `fetch` API, but my request immediately gets blocked..

Is there any workaround for this? Using an `async` function or waiting for the request to finish results in a popup confirmation box, which I want to avoid.

Here is my code (edited for brevity):

```
    window.onbeforeunload = () => {
        let endSessionRes = fetch('/api/endSession', {
          method: 'POST',
        });
      }
      return;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The `keepalive` option in Fetch does just the thing!

Here's the updated code that works (no dialog box too!)

```
    window.onbeforeunload = () => {
        let endSessionRes = fetch('/api/endSession', {
          method: 'POST',
          keepAlive: true,
         // ...
        });
      }
      return;
    };
```